# When i try to go through the file does it overwrite the array I am trying to save to?

Tags: c, file

```
    char * names[10];
    int i = 0;
    char theRow[20];

    while (fgets(theRow, 80 , fp) != NULL) {
        names[i] = theRow;
        i++;
    }
```

The output of the array I am trying to save to is all the same depending on the last element.

for ex. file has (`hi`, `I` , `2`, `3`, `karl`)
the array then becomes (`karl`,`karl`,`karl`,`karl`,`karl`)

Did i miss something or what can it be?

Comment: Where are you allocating memory for the pointers in `names[10];`? What's `nameRow`? Please post your whole code.

Comment: ops sorry its supposed to be theRow, but what do you mean allocating memory? the array still exists it just overrites the old indexes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `names[i] = nameRow;`, you are storing the same pointer (to the same block of memory) again and again, but with every line you read, you overwrite the *contents* if this single chunk of memory.

You need to copy the contents you read in into your buffer `nameRow`, before you overwrite it then in the next iteration of the loop.

```
names[i] = strdup(nameRow);
```

Function `strdup` does two things, (1) it reserves memory large enough to hold a copy of `nameRow` (using `malloc`), and (2) it copies the content then.

This also makes clear that you'll have to `free` each entry copied later.

And, though widely adopted, `strdup` is not part of standard C; so in order to be platform independent, you'll have to write...

```
names[i] = malloc(strlen(nameRow)+1);
strcpy(names[i],nameRow);
```

Comment: Be sure that 10 is the maximum number of element you have in your files.

Comment: `strdup` creates a copy using `malloc`, so don't forget to call `free` on each string when you are finished using them